# resizable sidebar in Kibana UI

Tags: kibana

The complete field name is not visible in Kibana navigation bar. If I pass my mouse on the field, it shows the full text for e.g. "requestParameter.allocationID". Should I check each and every field by pointing the mouse? The sidebar width can not be changed or adjusted to fit the entire fieldname?

[image]

Comment: Only the word "requestParameters" is visible for all fields!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unresolved issue [#737](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/737) from November 2013. You are not alone requesting this feature. Deeply in the comment section, there is a [comment](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/737#issuecomment-562163724) referring to the issue [#38646](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/38646) where the progress can be tracked.

I bet this will be released very soon.

For now, feel free to pick one of possible workarounds:

- Place a mouse pointer over a label to display its full content (not comfortable)
- Resize it manually using devtools. (right-click and `Inspect` in Google Chrome)